# Carregar de dentro da partialview js/css

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, razor, partialview

Bom dia,`insira o código aqui`

Não estou conseguindo carregar .js/.css ao carregar a partialview

no layout

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    ...
    @RenderSection("header", required: false)
</head>

<body>
    ...
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

na view index

```
@section header{
    @Styles.Render(...)<carrega de boa>
    @Scripts.Render(...)<carrega de boa>
}

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Usuários";
}

<div class="row">
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Cadastros/_ListaUsuarios.cshtml")

</div>

@section Scripts {
     ...
}
```

na partialview

```
@section header{
    @Scripts.Render("~/Content/plugins/datatables/js")  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<NÃO CARREGA>
}

<table id="#example" class="table-striped table-bordered tableHeader-skin-blue" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            ....
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Gostaria de saber porque  o script que eu coloquei na partialview não está sendo adicionado ao html?

Alguém saberia me dizer?

Answer (score 0):

No seu web.config esta permitindo o debug?

```
 <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true|false" />
```

Como você esta usando apenas um arquivo javascript, as vezes compensa mais chama-lo no método nativo:

```
<script src="~/Content/plugins/datatables/arquivo_min.js"></script>
```

E você pode centralizar todos os seus arquivos js e css na layout padrão(master page), ou na página pai.

Se ainda não funcionar, roda no Chrome, da um F12 e veja na aba Console os erros da sua página, provavelmente estará informando qual o erro esta ocorrendo.

Qualquer coisa cola aqui o erro pra nós.

Comment: Obrigado Fabricio,

eu estou colocando:
@section header{
    @Scripts.Render("~/Content/plugins/datatables/js")  
}
na partial e nem é adicionado na página.

O objetivo de colocar na partial é que quando eu adicionar a partial em qualquer outra página eu não precise me preocupar em add o JS/CSS, não sei se é boa prática mas como iriei usar muito essa partial(que será uma tabela de usuário não queria ficar toda hora declarando esse cara).

Comment: E deu certo mudando alguma das coisas que falei? Tentou ver no console do Chrome o erro?

Comment: Está sim como debug e funcionando, só não carrega a dll, o section header da partial não é carregado no header da página